# Run macro in background

Tags: vba, excel

I have some trouble with VBA macros.

1. While opening a Excel file (`FILE1.xls`) which has a macro (the macro contains a userform with command buttons which i programmed it to use those command buttons as shortcuts to folders, website etc...). There is no problem with this step.
2. I am trying to open a new Excel file (`FILE2.xls`) without macro (for example a file i received by mail) when I open the file it's invisible. I think it's a problem coming from my macro.

So I want to run this macro in background and be able to open 6 different Excel files (for example).

I have been searching to solve this problem for a long time.

Comment: No need to apologize for language; other users can edit your post for clarity, or ask for more detail through comments like this one. You might want to give more information about the process and where it breaks. For example, does Excel open FILE2.xls if you *dont* have FILE1.xls open? Can you give more information about what you've tried, and what the results have been?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the UserForms `ShowModal` property to `False` in its properties window to prevent it blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the below function to open several workbooks in the background.

Example call:

```
Set newWorkbook = GetWorkbook(scoreCardLink)
```

Function:

```
Public Function GetWorkbook(fullFileName As String) As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim result As Workbook
Dim sFileName As String
On Error Resume Next

strFilePath = fullFileName
vParts = Split(strFilePath, "/")
sFileName = vParts(UBound(vParts))

Set result = Workbooks(sFileName)
If (result Is Nothing) Then
    Application.enableEvents = False
    Set result = Workbooks.Open(fullFileName, ReadOnly = True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommend = False)
End If
Set GetWorkbook = result
End Function
```